# diffeomorphism is always a composition of two diffeomorphisms

Tags: real-analysis, jacobian

This is not a question about two diffeomorphisms composition.

Consider $\Phi : \Omega \to \widetilde\Omega$, where $\Phi$ is diffeomorphism, $\Omega$ and $ \widetilde\Omega$ are open subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I want to proof that $\forall a \in \Omega$, $\forall k \in \mathbb{N} < n$ there exist $U_a \subset \Omega$ and diffeomorphisms $\Phi_1: U_a \to \Phi_1(U_a), \Phi_2: \Phi_1(U_a) \to \widetilde\Omega$, such that $\Phi |_{U_a} = \Phi_2 \circ \Phi_1$ and $\Phi_1$ remains $k$ coordinates, while $\Phi_2$ remains $n - k$ other coordinates.

What I've done already:
Let us consider $x \in \mathbb{R^k}, y \in \mathbb{R^{n - k}}$. Rewrite $\Phi(x, y) = (f(x, y), g(x, y))$ in the same manner. Now we want that $\Phi_1(x, y) = (x, \phi(x, y)), \Phi_2(x, y) = (\psi(x, y), y)$. Let's write a composition of them: $(f(x, y), g(x, y)) = \Phi(x, y) = \Phi_2 \circ \Phi_1(x, y) = \Phi_2(x, \phi(x, y)) = (\psi(x, \phi(x, y)), \phi(x, y))$. Now we can observe that $\phi = g$. What's left is to show that there exists $\psi$ such that $\psi(x, \phi(x, y)) = f(x, y)$. Note that it's eqivalent to $f = \psi \circ \Phi_1$. Now we want to apply the inverse function theorem: $\psi = f \circ \Phi_1^{-1}$. Can you help me to proceed?

Comment: What does it mean "changes $k$ others"?

Comment: It obviously means that if $\Phi_1$ changes k coordinates, $\Phi_2$ doesn't. I now rewrote it to "changes k other coordinates".

Comment: This is not at all obvious and still very much unclear. For instance, the map $f(x,y)=(x,y+\sin(x))$ changes the 2nd coordinate for some points but not for other points. Does it count as "changing the 2nd coordinate?" What about the identity map? Does it count as "changing the 2nd coordinate?" (It changes the 2nd coordinate for the empty set of points, if you want the precise statement.)

Comment: I don't get your question now. The statement of theorem expands in the section that is right below.
Focus on what "not changing coordinate" means. Yet, this is still obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Since everyone was busy stating "it's very much unclear", I decided to post the end of proof.

So, to apply inverse function theorem on $\Phi_1$, we need it to be continuously differentiable and it's Jacobian at point a non zero (invertible).

Differentiability (continuous) follows from differentiability of identity map $x \to x$ and f. Now let's write a Jacobian
\begin{pmatrix}
E & 0\\
f_x' & f_y'
\end{pmatrix}. It is equal to $det(f_y')$. Note that it is a k-sized minor of $\Phi$. Since $\Phi$ is diffeomorphism, det$\Phi' \neq 0$ and there exist some k-sized non-zero minor. Now we can swap the coordinates as we want the right bottom minor to be non-zero.

Comment: The main confusion here comes from this swap possibility. What if this minor is not centralized (i.e. we got something like $M_{1, 3}$)? Then we can't swap coordinates so it will be in the right corner at the bottom. If someone could expand it from here I would be glad.